# Is it possible to simultaneously define and assign an array to an object's property?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

Instead of first defining arrays then assigning them to my object's properties, I'm wondering if I could do both at the same time. So I have:

```
const myArray = [var1, var2]
const obj = { myProperty: myArray }
```

I'd like to do something like that instead:

```
const obj = { myProperty: [var1, var2] }
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but perhaps there's a way to make it work?

Comment: *"Obviously that doesn't work"* It does. You can put *any* expression at the initializer position of a property. An array literal is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
const var1 = "hello";
const var2 = "world";
const obj = { myProperty: [var1, var2] }
console.log("Object", obj);
```

I am wondering that you need this.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to say you need a reference to the array assigned to the property, then yes it's possible, as JS supports assignment expressions.

```js
const var1 = "hello";
const var2 = "world";
const obj = { myProperty: arr = [var1, var2] }
console.log(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

arr can be used as a reference to the array.